# sub string in char* in c++ with strtok to the end of the row

Tags: c++, c, text, substring, strtok

I try to cat a string that type in char* in c++
this is my code

```
void DBManager::printMatched(char* line, char* fileName)
{
    line = strtok(line,"Show");
    char* teamAName = strtok(line," ");
    char* teamACity = strtok(NULL,"-");
    char* teamBName = strtok(NULL," ");
    char* teamBCity = strtok(NULL,"\n");
}
```

and this is the text in line
"Show abcde fghij - klmnop qrstu"

this is the variable data:

```
 teamAName = abcde
 teamACity = fghij
 teamBName = klmnop
 teamBCity = qrs
```

how can i fix teamBCity i need to cut to the in of the row.

i work on Linux system.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the calling routine.  How is `printMatched()` called?

Comment: when i call the functuin there is \n in the end of the row but after line = strtok(line,"Show"); the \n is down..

Comment: Please show the code that uses `printMatched()` and prints `teamBCity`.  I suspect the problem is in how the argument for `line` is generated or how your printed `teamBCity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  Not entirely sure given your example.  It can obviously be improved upon and maybe you want to use more c++ish facilities?

```
void DBManager::printMatched(char* line, char* fileName)
{
    char* linecpy   = strdup(line);

    char* dummy     = strtok(linecpy," ");
    char* teamAName = strtok(NULL," ");
    char* teamACity = strtok(NULL," ");
          dummy     = strtok(NULL," ");
    char* teamBName = strtok(NULL," ");
    char* teamBCity = strtok(NULL," \n");

    printf("teamAName %s\n", teamAName);
    printf("teamACity %s\n", teamACity);
    printf("teamBName %s\n", teamBName);
    printf("teamBCity %s\n", teamBCity);

    // do something with strings here?
}
```